# Windows update downloader.Download() fail

Tags: vbscript, jscript, windows-update

I come across a sample vbscript program from Microsoft site regarding Windows Update(named WUA_SearchDownloadInstall.vbs).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387102%28VS.85%29.aspx

```
Set updateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
Set updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateupdateSearcher()

WScript.Echo "Searching for updates..." & vbCRLF

Set searchResult = _
updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'")


WScript.Echo "List of applicable items on the machine:"

For I = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count-1
    Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
    WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> " & update.Title
Next

If searchResult.Updates.Count = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "There are no applicable updates."
    WScript.Quit
End If

WScript.Echo vbCRLF & "Creating collection of updates to download:"

Set updatesToDownload = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl")

For I = 0 to searchResult.Updates.Count-1
    Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
    WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> adding: " & update.Title 
    updatesToDownload.Add(update)
Next

WScript.Echo vbCRLF & "Downloading updates..."

Set downloader = updateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader() 
downloader.Updates = updatesToDownload
downloader.Download()

WScript.Echo  vbCRLF & "List of downloaded updates:"

For I = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count-1
    Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
    If update.IsDownloaded Then
       WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> " & update.Title 
    End If
Next

Set updatesToInstall = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl")

WScript.Echo  vbCRLF & _
"Creating collection of downloaded updates to install:" 

For I = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count-1
    set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
    If update.IsDownloaded = true Then
       WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> adding:  " & update.Title 
       updatesToInstall.Add(update) 
    End If
Next

WScript.Echo  vbCRLF & "Would you like to install updates now? (Y/N)"
strInput = WScript.StdIn.Readline
WScript.Echo 

If (strInput = "N" or strInput = "n") Then 
    WScript.Quit
ElseIf (strInput = "Y" or strInput = "y") Then
    WScript.Echo "Installing updates..."
    Set installer = updateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller()
    installer.Updates = updatesToInstall
    Set installationResult = installer.Install()

    'Output results of install
    WScript.Echo "Installation Result: " & _
    installationResult.ResultCode 
    WScript.Echo "Reboot Required: " & _ 
    installationResult.RebootRequired & vbCRLF 
    WScript.Echo "Listing of updates installed " & _
     "and individual installation results:" 

    For I = 0 to updatesToInstall.Count - 1
        WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> " & _
        updatesToInstall.Item(i).Title & _
        ": " & installationResult.GetUpdateResult(i).ResultCode         
    Next
End If
```

**his script runs well until it reaches**

```
downloader.Download()
```

On that line, the CMD window outputs

```
C:\wu-install\WUA_SearchDownloadInstall.vbs(37, 1) (null): 0x80240044
```

By adding a printf line before `downloader.Download()` , I can see that the error is asserted immediately in Download().

My question is: How can I find clue to know the error reason? May be there is way to catch the exception and let output some detailed error message.

I tried with the help of this post( [Seem like a VBscript exception, how to cope with?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9731688/151453) ), and write around the problem line:

```
On Error Resume Next 
downloader.Download()
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    WScript.Echo Err.Description
    WScript.Quit 4
End If
On Error Goto 0
```

But `WScript.Echo Err.Description` outputs nothing. How can I do?

[image]

My environment: Windows 7 32-bit.

[[[ UPDATE ]]]

I'm back on this question. I've updated my script to use JScript. Yes, it is convenient than VBScript.

Now I have such code snippet:

```
var downloader = updsession.CreateUpdateDownloader() 
downloader.Updates = updatesToDownload
try {
    downloader.Download()
}
catch(err) {
    WScript.Echo("Oops, Download error.")
    WScript.Echo("Possible reason:")
    WScript.Echo("* On Windows Vista/7, This requires you Run as Administrator.")
    WScript.Quit(3)
}
```

Remaining question is: How do I get error code from Download() so that I can check error reason. The page at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx seems too coarse for me to find the answer.

Waiting for your help again. Thank you.

Comment: I highly recommend you start a new question instead of editing this one.  Your original question has already been addressed.  You can include a link to this question as background information.

Answer (score 3):

You are receiving this error because the Windows Updater API requires elevated priveleges.  Launching your script in an elevated command prompt should solve the issue.

As a side note, you should make sure that you are connected to the internet, the Windows Update service is enabled, and that there are no pending update installations (i.e. waiting to install at shutdown).  These things will also cause errors.

[edit]

You should be able to retrieve the status from inside the the library.  The `Download` method returns a [status code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Assigning its result to a variable may prevent your script from bombing out.  If not, try using `On Error Goto Next` to get around it.  You can find the various result codes and error codes below.

[Windows Update Agent Result Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[WUA Networking Error Codes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939837%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. You're right. Run as Administrator on Win7 solves this problem. But it would be better if the program provides a way to tell user what caused that error. If not, we have to check one by one which one of the 3+ cases is encountered.

Comment: A proper script would check for all three instances in an effort to be thorough.  However, this particular error only results from not having elevated priveleges.

Comment: What about the there will be a fourth in the future? There should be a way to get an error description from inside the library.