# Can't define f.WriteLine (vbscript)

Tags: variables, vbscript

I want to log my windows updates script, but I get the following error.

```
800a005b object variable not setline: 28, 1
```

which refers to:

```
f.WriteLine 'some text here'
```

I also tried `Dim f.WriteLine` and `Dim f`, neither of which solve my problem.

What should I do to resolve this?

Full code:

```
set test = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
set f = fso.CreateTextFile(write_to_File,8)

Dim fso
Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\output.txt", 2)


f.Close
'End of Script

'ServerSelection values
ssDefault = 0
ssManagedServer   = 1
ssWindowsUpdate   = 2
ssOthers          = 3

strComputer = "." ' Local Computer

'InStr values
intSearchStartChar = 1

dim strTitle

Set updateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
Set updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateupdateSearcher()

updateSearcher.ServerSelection = ssWindowsUpdate
Set searchResult = updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'")

f.WriteLine "Lijst met beschikbare updates op deze machine:"

For I = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count-1
    Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
    WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> " & update.Title
Next

If searchResult.Updates.Count = 0 Then
    f.WriteLine "Er zijn geen updates beschikbaar."
    WScript.Quit
End If

f.WriteLine vbCRLF & "Aanmaken lijst met te downloaden updates:"

Set updatesToDownload = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl")

For I = 0 to searchResult.Updates.Count-1
    Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
    addThisUpdate = false
    If update.InstallationBehavior.CanRequestUserInput = true Then
        WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> skipping: " & update.Title & _
        " because it requires user input"
    Else
        If update.EulaAccepted = false Then
            WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> note: " & update.Title & _
            " has a license agreement that must be accepted:"
            WScript.Echo update.EulaText
                 update.AcceptEula()
                addThisUpdate = false
        Else
            addThisUpdate = false
        End If
    End If
    If addThisUpdate = true Then
        WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> adding: " & update.Title 
        updatesToDownload.Add(update)
    End If
Next

If updatesToDownload.Count = 0 Then
    f.WriteLine "All applicable updates were skipped."
    WScript.Quit
End If

f.WriteLine vbCRLF & "Downloading updates..."

Set downloader = updateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader() 
downloader.Updates = updatesToDownload
downloader.Download()

Set updatesToInstall = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl")

rebootMayBeRequired = false

f.WriteLine vbCRLF & "Successfully downloaded updates:"

For I = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count-1
    set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
    If update.IsDownloaded = true Then
        WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> " & update.Title 
        updatesToInstall.Add(update)    
        If update.InstallationBehavior.RebootBehavior > 0 Then
            rebootMayBeRequired = true
        End If
    End If
Next

If updatesToInstall.Count = 0 Then
    f.WriteLine "No updates were successfully downloaded."
    WScript.Quit
End If

If rebootMayBeRequired = true Then
    f.WriteLine vbCRLF & "These updates may require a reboot."
End If

    f.WriteLine "Installing updates..."
    Set installer = updateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller()
    installer.Updates = updatesToInstall
    Set installationResult = installer.Install()

    'Output results of install
    f.WriteLine "Installation Result: " & _
    installationResult.ResultCode 
    f.WriteLine "Reboot Required: " & _ 
    installationResult.RebootRequired & vbCRLF 
    f.WriteLine "Listing of updates installed " & _
    "and individual installation results:" 

    For I = 0 to updatesToInstall.Count - 1
        WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> " & _
        updatesToInstall.Item(i).Title & _
        ": " & installationResult.GetUpdateResult(i).ResultCode         
    Next


Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Shutdown)}!\\" & _
            strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colOS = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")

For Each objOS in colOS
    objOS.Reboot()
Next
```

Comment: user3611729 : For better answer, post your complete code.

Comment: Is `f` a `FileSystemObject`?

Comment: @PankajJaju - as .Writeline is intended to be used on f, let's hope not.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner - should have asked the full question .. what i meant to ask was that is `f` points to any file which might be created or opened using FSO :-)

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for the help so far.

I am going to post the code, because i still cant figure it out.. i posted it at the main question

Answer (score 0):

This code should enable you to use writeline, my example is to a log file

Firstly set `test` to be a `"Scripting.FileSystemObject"`
Next set your `f` to equal `test` and `test` points to a log file location (`write_to_file`), and append to it using value `8`
Finally use the `f.writeline` line to write strings to the log file

```
set test = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
set f = test.OpenTextFile(write_to_File,8)

f.writeline "Some text here"
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the help so far! I still can not figure this error out.. so i posted the full code. Line 28, 1 is the first f.writeline :)

Comment: aren't you "f.Close" closing the file before writing to it? f.close should occur after you have finished with the file. Also add option explicit to the top of the script as it may give more information on the error

Comment: Yeah, that wasnt very smart.. so i just did that, and i defiend alot of variables, but now i am getting another error :(

This one: (0x)80240044

Comment: where does this occur? With option explicit it means you have to define all your variables and objects with Dim

Comment: Hey, 

This occurs at line 55, char 18. 

Kind regards

Ruga

Comment: what is the line of code? Line 55 may have changed since the original code post

Comment: Its from the eula:

update.AcceptEula()

Thanks for al the help so far!

Comment: i think you would want to use this link here for help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740694/windows-update-downloader-download-fail Also the questions you answer know are very off topic the original question. If my solution worked for the f.writeline, please accept the answer and then create a new question about the windows_updater.vbs

Comment: You are right, we are getting off topic. My computer has a problem with windows updates that i want to fix first. Thanks for all the help so far, if i have a question i'll make a new topic. Kind regards, Ruga